# How do I select specific names of a column with Content?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello I've got a problem with SQL Server 2012,

```
SELECT e.especes,COUNT(*) AS [nombre de sujets],
    STUFF((SELECT  ',' + ' ' + a.nom 
              FROM  animal a,espece e
              where e.IDESPECE = a.IDESPECE
              FOR XML PATH (''))
              , 1, 1, '')  AS noms
    INTO statEspece 
    from espece e,animal a 
    WHERE e.IDESPECE = a.IDESPECE 
    GROUP BY a.IDESPECE, e.especes;
```

Even if i try to put this line:

> where e.IDESPECE = a.IDESPECE

the name column is filled with all the animals of the dbo.animal.nom .

The output looks like this :

```
Animal  Number   Names
Tigre   2   Tigrou, Chita, Chloe, Jumbo, Zaza, Coco, Kahn, King
Lion    1   Tigrou, Chita, Chloe, Jumbo, Zaza, Coco, Kahn, King
Zèbre   1   Tigrou, Chita, Chloe, Jumbo, Zaza, Coco, Kahn, King
Singe   2   Tigrou, Chita, Chloe, Jumbo, Zaza, Coco, Kahn, King
other   1   Tigrou, Chita, Chloe, Jumbo, Zaza, Coco, Kahn, King
other   1   Tigrou, Chita, Chloe, Jumbo, Zaza, Coco, Kahn, King
```

Can anybody please explain me why it returns me all the names in the database?

Comment: Explain what do you expect out of this query. Add more details so that we can try to answer your question.

Comment: the output said they are 2 tiger( with name Tigrou and kahn), so i want in my name column having the specific names of the tigers, but in each line it return me all the animal names :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT e.especes,COUNT(*) AS [nombre de sujets],
STUFF((SELECT  ',' + ' ' + a1.nom 
          FROM  animal a1,espece e1
          where e1.IDESPECE = a1.IDESPECE AND a1.IDESPECE=a.IDESPECE
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS noms
INTO statEspece 
from espece e,animal a 
WHERE e.IDESPECE = a.IDESPECE 
GROUP BY a.IDESPECE, e.especes;
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, now it return me this :                         Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Column 'e.IDESPECE' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: I amended it to use a.idespece in the correlated query. Could you please try now.